# How to customize parsleyjs error message for alphanum & email type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation, parsley.js

In the [documentation of parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-ui-for-field), it is asked to specify

```
data-parsley-'contraint'-message = "My message"
```

to get the desirable error message for a given field. I wish to customize the error message for a valid email and a valid alphanumeric type field in the form. I tried with,

```
'parsley-type-email-message' => 'Invalid format'
```

and

```
'parsley-type-alphanum-message' => 'Alphanumeric only'
```

based on old documentation but they do not seem to work.

What should I specify in constraint for each of these?

Answer (score 3):

Got it! Use the following

```
'data-parsley-type-message' => 'Your message'
```

without specifying email or alphanum type in the data attribute because there is just one input field in question at a time.

The documentation for this [here](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.0.md#uiux).